# What does the X-Heroku-Dynos-In-Use header mean?

Tags: heroku

Heroku provides the header X-Heroku-Dynos-In-Use to applications, but offers scant documentation of what this means (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing):

```
X-Heroku-Dynos-In-Use: the number of dynos currently serving requests
```

We have a node.js app with 50+ dynos that is still getting H12 timeouts. X-Heroku-Dynos-In-Use is often 1, and never more than 2 or 3. So clearly this isn't the # of dynos in use across the application. What does this number actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've clarified the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) on that header a little bit: "`X-Heroku-Dynos-In-Use`: the number of dynos currently serving requests for this router. Because other requests may be routed by other routers this number is not a good indication of the total number of dynos currently handling requests for an app."